# Is there a leak in this copy code?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

Is there a leak in this code?

```
// Move the group
 Group *movedGroup = [[Group alloc] init];
 movedGroup = [[[[GroupList sharedGroupList] groups] objectAtIndex:fromIndex] copy];
 [[GroupList sharedGroupList] deleteGroup:fromIndex];
 [[GroupList sharedGroupList] insertGroup:movedGroup atIndex:toIndex];

 // Update the loadedGroupIndex pointer
 if (loadedGroupIndex < fromIndex & loadedGroupIndex >= toIndex) {
  loadedGroupIndex = loadedGroupIndex + 1;
 } else if (loadedGroupIndex > fromIndex & loadedGroupIndex < toIndex) {
  loadedGroupIndex = loadedGroupIndex - 1;
 } else if (loadedGroupIndex == fromIndex) {
  loadedGroupIndex = toIndex;
 }
 [movedGroup release]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first instantiated Group will leak away. You lost the reference to it (assigning `movedGroup = ...`) and it's not marked for autorelease. You could reduce those first two lines to:

```
Group *movedGroup = [[[[GroupList sharedGroupList] groups] objectAtIndex:fromIndex] copy];
```

and it will do the same, with no leak.

Comment: has it right. movedGroup was *alloced*, which means it became a pointer to a chunk of memory for holding a Group object. Then you pointed away from that object and instead pointed it to your *copied* object. This left the alloced Group object hanging, with nothing pointing to it anymore. If you *Build and Analyze* your project the analyzer will tell you that nothing was done with the object you created on the first line and that it's a possible leak (which it is).

Comment: Yeah, obvious in retrospect.  And it was a Build and Analyze that pointed this out to me.  I just wanted to make sure I understood it properly.  Thanks for the input.